# Apache ECharts 5.5.0: How to propagate mouse wheel event?

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts, apache-echarts

The default behavior of ECharts causes mouse wheel to zoom the chart.
I have several vertically arranged ECharts that do not fit on one screen. So I have a scrollable page.

I want mouse wheel to scroll the page up/down.
The problem is that ECharts zooms its content and consumes the event so that it is not propagated to the parent.

Even if I turn off the zooming e.g. via `DataZoom.zoomOnMouseWheel = 'ctrl'`, ECharts still consumes the event so that the page is not scrolled.

Is there a possibility that ECharts propagates the event to the parent as long as Ctrl is not pressed so that the page is scrolled?

```js
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  var chartDom = document.getElementById('main' + i);
  var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
  var option;

  option = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value'
    },
    dataZoom: [
      {
        type: 'inside',
        zoomOnMouseWheel: 'ctrl'
      }
    ],
    series: [
      {
        data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
        type: 'line'
      }
    ]
  };

  option && myChart.setOption(option);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main0" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
<div id="main1" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
<div id="main2" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Disable mouseWheel on the chart

If you just want to *always* disable scrolling on the chart so you can scroll the page even when the cursor is above the chart, add `zoomLock: true` in the dataZoom:

```js
dataZoom: [
  {
    type: 'inside',
    zoomOnMouseWheel: 'ctrl',
    zoomLock: true
  }
],
```

### Enable mouseWheel on the chart only when pressing a key

It is currently not possible to enable mouseWheel events on a chart only when a key is pressed (and disable it when that key isn't pressed).

The option `DataZoom.zoomOnMouseWheel = 'ctrl'` only disables *zooming* when the `ctrl` key isn't pressed, but the chart still catches the mouseWheel event (as you said in your post).

This is an issue known for a long time on Echarts but it's still not resolved.
See the answers on **[this opened issue on Echarts github](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/10079)** for **interesting  workarounds** that some users suggested.